# Document tabs in texmaker

Tags: text-editor, latex, tabs

Is there any way to get texmaker to display the currently open documents in tabs (like every other program) instead of a drop down menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to edit the source yourself, no.

It makes *no* sense that a drop-down is used instead of tabs.

But if you go to "View->List of open files" in the menu, and you make sure the Structure panel is open, a clickable list of open files will appear that is helpful when you have lots of files open.